# Return associative array from function

Tags: php

This is how I would normally run a loop with database information

```
        $query = "SELECT * from courses ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { }
```

Now `$row[]` can be used to represent database information within the loop.

My problem is that I'll be utilizing this query a lot for separate while loops. However, I don't wish to have to complete this statement every time I require it, so I want a function to be able to refer to with any variables required.

For instance, I tried.

```
function retrieve_assoc_array_limit4($table) {  
    $user = '***';
    $pass = '***';
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', $user, $pass);

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(?, $table);
        $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $row;
}
```

But when trying to while it I get an unlimited amount of returns of the same information whiled.

```
while($row = retrieve_assoc_array_limit4($table_name)) {
    exho $data;
}
```

My question is how logically to use the first code in a function so that I can use it in the same with without writing out the full statement relentlessly.

Comment: You might want to consider generators if you're on PHP5.5 or above; but consider writing a generic function where limit is passed as an argument rather than individually named functions for each different limit that you want to use

Comment: 5.4.12 is the version I'm using.

Comment: Note that you __can't__ bind table or column names

Comment: Right okay, so I'll need separate functions for table/column names. However how about retrieving all the information as the first code brings?

Comment: You don't __need__ separate functions for different table/column names; but you can't __bind__ them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many ways of doing this, to use your code with little changes:

calling fetchAll() instead of fetch():

```
function retrieve_assoc_array_limit4($table) {  
    $user = '***';
    $pass = '***';
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', $user, $pass);

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(?, $table);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $rows;
}
```

then call your function and do a while or foreach:

```
$rows = retrieve_assoc_array_limit4($table_name);
foreach($rows as $row){
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, this works brilliantly. Now I just need to learn how to variable the table name. Thanks again.